# RegisterHotKey prevents from Textbox to receive input

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, registerhotkey

TL;DR - Want to detect global hotkeys without interfering other applications from reading keyboard input. RegisterHotKey interrupts regular input, so that's a no go.

Hello there and thank you for your time,

I've been recently fiddling around with WPF, trying to learn as I go and decided to do a small project to help me learn faster.

I have run into this problem, which is not quite exactly a problem, more of a logical contradiction, I would say.

What I've been doing is registering global key presses. While my window is either the top window or another one is highlighted, register every key press there is on Windows. I have been using the RegisterHotKey function which tells the computer to interpret keyboard input differently, if I understand properly. Which prevents me from using the keyboard as I would normally while this application is open in the background.

Every search I make comes up empty, they all lead me to RegisterHotKey which might not be the right solution in my case. I want to read global key presses while still keeping the same old keyboard input.

Even a slight suggestion on how this might be done will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters I'd like to say that down voting a question which was not offensive, did not go against the rules and was of a completely stuck programmer seeking help after several days of attempting to solve it on his own.. that's just pure evil.

Anyway, after realizing what I want cannot be done using RegisterHotKey, I decided to seek a solution elsewhere.
I ended up setting a hook on the low level keyboard input,
I do not have my code since I'm on my way to work, I'll post it later on today.

The main conclusion: if you want to read global key presses or global hot keys, if you want, while not interrupting other applications, you will probably want to use a hook, as mentioned in the above paragraph.